# Normalized image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to calculate the boundary of the signature image before going to Moment Invariant, the algorithm should check from left to the right the first white pixel is the left boundary and the last white pixel is the right boundary. Similarly from top to the bottom.

My research step:

1. Data Acquisition
2. Preprocessing
3. Signature Boundary Calculation
4. Moment invariant
5. fkcn

This is my code so far

```
a=imread('ttd.bmp');  
b=rgb2gray(a);  
c=im2bw(b);  
c=~c;  
c=1-c;  
c=(c == 0);  
imshow(c);
```

Comment: This is a binary image. why wud u normalize it

Comment: if your problem is only for ploting imshow(c,[]) does the job. But... as Mujtaba says, the iamge is binary, 0-1 range. Normalizing it is something it doesnt make any sense

Comment: @AnderBiguri I want to normalized an image using moment invariant before I want to classified the signature image using Fuzzy Kohonen Clustering Network and I'm stuck in inverted image

Comment: @MujtabaHasan is Binary image needed only in classified? I want to classified the signature whether it's fake or not.

Comment: Are you looking for [regionprops](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html)? As in `regionprops(c,'boundingbox')`? Also, why are you inverting your image 3 times?

Comment: @beaker Sorry I'm a newbie, so regionprops is needed to make a bounding box for my inverted binary image? like this   (smallestX,smallestY)-----------------(largestX,smallestY)    
      |                                      |
      |                                      |          
      |                                      | 
      |                                      |
(smallestX,largestY)------------------(largestX,largestY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalize? You mean map it to range [0,1] ? `img` is your single channel input image you want to map:

```
imgNormalized = (img-min(min(img)))./(max(max(img))-min(min(img)))
```

Comment: I want to calculate the boundary of the signature image before going to Moment Invariant, the algorithm should check from left to the right the first white pixel is the left boundary and the last white pixel is the right boundary. Similarly from top to the bottom.